# Pyglet, exit after all sounds played

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, pyglet

AVbin is installed. Both .wav and .mp3 files work.

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.media.load('A.mp3')
music.play()

player = pyglet.media.Player()
player.queue( pyglet.media.load('B.mp3'))
player.queue( pyglet.media.load('C.wav'))

player.play()


pyglet.app.run()

pyglet.app.exit()
```

---

I want to create a program that plays A, then plays the queue with B and then C, and finally quits after all three sounds play.

I tried the code above but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36859083/7398353) post, "this is [solely] because app.run() is a never-ending loop."

---

*How can I modify my code minimally so that the program quits after the three sounds are played?* 
***Bonus***, but how can I modify my code minimally so that the program can play two (or more) sound files, E.mp3 and F.mp3, at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because what you're asking is not as simple as you'd might think it is.
I've put together a code example with as much comments as I possibly could fit in without making the example to hard to read.

Below the code, I'll try to explain a few key functions as detailed as possible.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from collections import OrderedDict

key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self, width=800, height=600, fps=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(main, self).__init__(width, height, *args, **kwargs)

        self.keys = OrderedDict() # This just keeps track of which keys we're holding down. In case we want to do repeated input.
        self.alive = 1 # And as long as this is True, we'll keep on rendering.

        ## Add more songs to the list, either here, via input() from the console or on_key_ress() function below.
        self.songs = ['A.wav', 'B.wav', 'C.wav']
        self.song_pool = None

        self.player = pyglet.media.Player()
        for song in self.songs:
            media = pyglet.media.load(song)
            if self.song_pool is None:
                ## == if the Song Pool hasn't been setup,
                ##    we'll set one up. Because we need to know the audio_format()
                ##    we can't really set it up in advance (consists more information than just 'mp3' or 'wav')
                self.song_pool = pyglet.media.SourceGroup(media.audio_format, None)
            ## == Queue the media into the song pool.
            self.song_pool.queue(pyglet.media.load(song))

        ## == And then, queue the song_pool into the player.
        ##    We do this because SourceGroup (song_pool) as a function called
        ##    .has_next() which we'll require later on.
        self.player.queue(self.song_pool)
        ## == Normally, you would do self.player.eos_action = self.function()
        ##    But for whatever windows reasons, this doesn't work for me in testing.
        ##    So below is a manual workaround that works about as good.

        self.current_track = pyglet.text.Label('', x=width/2, y=height/2+50, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
        self.current_time = pyglet.text.Label('', x=width/2, y=height/2-50, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')


    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        try:
            del self.keys[symbol]
        except:
            pass

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

        elif symbol == key.SPACE:
            if self.player.playing:
                self.player.pause()
            else:
                self.player.play()

        elif symbol == key.RIGHT:
            self.player.seek(self.player.time + 15)

        ## == You could check the user input here,
        ##    and add more songs via the keyboard here.
        ##    For as long as self.song_pool has tracks,
        ##    this player will continue to play.

        self.keys[symbol] = True

    def end_of_tracks(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.alive=0

    def render(self):
        ## Clear the screen
        self.clear()
        
        ## == You could show some video, image or text here while the music plays.
        ##    I'll drop in a example where the current Track Name and time are playing.

        ## == Grab the media_info (if any, otherwise this returns None)
        media_info = self.player.source.info
        if not media_info:
            ## == if there were no meta-data, we'll show the file-name instead:
            media_info = self.player.source._file.name
        else:
            ## == But if we got meta data, we'll show "Artist - Track Title"
            media_info = media_info.author + ' - ' + media_info.title

        self.current_track.text = media_info
        self.current_track.draw()

        ## == This part exists of two things,
        ## 1. Grab the Current Time Stamp and the Song Duration.
        ##    Check if the song_pool() is at it's end, and if the track Cur>=Max -> We'll quit.
        ## *  (This is the manual workaround)
        cur_t, end_t = int(self.player.time), int(self.player.source._get_duration())
        if self.song_pool.has_next() is False and cur_t >= end_t:
            self.alive=False

        ## 2. Show the current time and maximum time in seconds to the user.
        self.current_time.text = str(cur_t)+'/'+str(end_t) + 'seconds'
        self.current_time.draw()

        ## This "renders" the graphics:
        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

x = main()
x.run()
```

Now, normally you'd decorate your way trough this with a bunch of functions.
But I like to subclass and OOP my way through any graphical libraries, because it gets messy quite fast otherwise.

So instead of `pyglet.app.run()`, I've got a custom made `run()` function.
All this does is mimic the `pyglet.app.run()`, for the most part. Enough to get going at least.

Because `player.eos_*` events appears to be broken.
I've added a manual example of how you could check if the songs are done playing or not.

This is a combination of `self.song_pool` [pyglet.media.SourceGroup](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/media/pyglet.media.SourceGroup.html), `self.player.time` [pyglet.media.player.time](https://pythonhosted.org/pyglet/api/pyglet.media.Player-class.html#time) and `self.player.source._get_duration()` which returns the track duration.

The `SourceGroup` gives us a `has_next()` function which tells us if we're at the end of the queued songs. The other two variables tells us if we've reached the end of the current track. This is all we need to determinate if we want to exit or not.

Now, I haven't technically added a way to add more songs. Because again, that would also be harder than you think. Unless you opt in for `if symbol == key.LCTRL: self.song_pool.queue(pyglet.media.load(input('Song: ')))` for instance. But again, all you would need to do, is add more songs to the `self.song_pool` queue, and there you go.

I hope this answers your question. Even the bonus one.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for the code sample! I was having a similar problem, but with video this time. With the trick to stop teh rendering loop, everything works now (except for mp4 videos... but this seems to be a problem with AVbin).

Comment: Just to mention.... pyglet 1.4.0a1 has moved from AVbin to ffmpeg, and now mp4 and several other formats are working nicely with pyglet Player!